# I want to transpose a loop of 5 columns and 100 rows into 1 row

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 columns and 100 rows of information I need to put into a single horizontal row.

for example:

red   green   blue  yellow
red   green   blue  yellow
red   green   blue  yellow
ect...

to

red   green   blue  yellow red   green   blue  yellow red   green   blue  yellow...ect

please help I have no idea how to create a macro so be as basic as possible! thank you

Comment: The example and output are the same in your question (because of the formatting here). Can you edit your answer. To add a newline you add **two spaces**. Also, to clarify your question, you have **an excel sheet** with 5 columns and 100 rows?

Comment: Typivally excel only has 256 columns so putting 5 columns of 100 rows into a single horizontal row is goign to cause issues. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does a transpose on the same sheet. Change the rows and column as required.
Hopefully you know how to open the VBA editor and run the macro.

```
Sub transpose()
Dim row
Dim targetRow
Dim targetColumn
Dim column
Dim columnMin
Dim columnMax
Dim rowMin
Dim rowMax
Dim tmp

rowMin = 1
rowMax = 2
columnMin = 1
columnMax = 5

targetColumn = 7
targetRow = 1

row = rowMin
While row <= rowMax

    column = columnMin

    While column <= columnMax

        Cells(row, column).Select
        tmp = ActiveCell.Value
        Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = tmp
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
        column = column + 1

    Wend

    row = row + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

What this does is loops over each row that is required.
Start at the first column that is required.
Loops over each column in that row, get the value and put in the target row and column. Then increment the target row.

I'm hoping there is enough example code here that you can make modifications yourself to solve your specific problem.

'edit
Damn. Just noticed that question asked for 1 row, but this does 1 column. Shouldn't be too hard to change.